# Custom customer address attribute not save in saled_order_address table for guest checkout order in magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2.4, onepage-checkout, custom-attributes

I Have created a custom address attribute.This field is show in checkout form.Field is created in sales_order_address table also. When i am saving the data from checkout this custom attribute value is not saving.

**This attribute is save fine when customer was logged in and not saving when guest checkout**.

> custom_attributes
> :
> {bl_flat_number: "BL678", phone_number: ""}
> bl_flat_number
> :
> "BL678"
> phone_number
> :
> "

I need to save the **bl_flat_number** to sales_order_address table when a guest checkout is happen.

How can i access this value from my plugin file.

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="Experius_ExtraCheckoutAddressFields_Plugin_Magento_Quote_Model_ShippingAddressManagement" sortOrder="10" type="Experius\ExtraCheckoutAddressFields\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement"/>
</type>
```

**ShippingAddressManagement.php** file

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Experius\ExtraCheckoutAddressFields\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model;
use Experius\ExtraCheckoutAddressFields\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
class ShippingAddressManagement
{

protected $helper;
protected $logger;

public function __construct(
    Data $helper,
    LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->helper = $helper;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function beforeAssign(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement $subject,
    $cartId,
    AddressInterface $address
) {
    $extAttributes = $address->getExtensionAttributes();
    $this->logger->critical("E2 BeforeAssign");
    if (!empty($extAttributes)) { $this->logger->critical(" In Side Flat Number".$extAttributes->getBlFlatNumber());
        if($extAttributes->getBlFlatNumber() != "")
        {
            $this->helper->transportFieldsFromExtensionAttributesToObject(
                $extAttributes,
                $address,
                'extra_checkout_shipping_address_fields'
            );
        }
    }
    return [$cartId, $address];
}
}
```

**Update - extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
    <attribute code="bl_flat_number" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
    <attribute code="bl_flat_number" type="string"/>
</extension_attributes>
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
    <attribute code="telephone" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
    <attribute code="phone_number" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
```

With this file i am unable to capture the custom attribute value, since guest checkout address is not saved. Any possible way to access this value and save in the quote_order_address table.

Comment: please upload your extension_attributes.xml and fieldset.xml file here.

Comment: @RohanHapani i have updated. please check